# Erro al tratar de ingresar al login en php con pdo

Tags: php

Tengo este problema al tratar de conectar a mi login. Los usuarios los pongo correctos y nunca ingresan. Me devuelve a index nuevamente.

```
session_start();
include("../clascn/cnxweb.php"); 
$user = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];
$latitud = $_POST['latitud'];
$longitud = $_POST['longitud'];
$accuracy = $_POST['acurracy'];
$cons="SELECT * u.UsuarioId,u.Nombre,u.IdUsuario,u.Administrador,u.PASSWORD,u.NivelId,n.nivel,n.pagina FROM Usuarios AS u 
LEFT JOIN niveles AS n ON n.nivelid = u.NivelId  where u.IdUsuario = '$user' and u.Password = '$pass'";
$query = $pdo->prepare($cons);
$query->execute();
$row = $query->fetch();
$iduser = $row['IdUsuario']; 
$pagina = $row['pagina'];
if ($iduser == ""){ echo 'hay un error...';
//  header("Location: index.php?error=true"); 
?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.location = "../index.php?error=true"
        </script>   
<?  }else{

    $_SESSION["user"] = $row['IdUsuario'];  
    $_SESSION['estado'] = 'Autenticado';
    $_SESSION['esadmin'] = $row['NivelId'];

    $fecha = date('Y-m-d');
    $hora = date('H:i:s');      
    $cons="insert into accesos (fecha, hora , usuario ,latitud,longitud,accuracy ) 
                        values ('$fecha','$hora','$iduser','$latitud','$longitud','$accuracy')";
    $query = $pdo->prepare($cons);
    $query->execute();

    //header('Location: menus.php');
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.location =  "<? echo $pagina ?>"
        </script>   
    <?  }
?>
```

Comment: Por de pronto no estás usando correctamente el PDO, los parámetros no se meten directamente en el SQL (eso se salta todo el proposito del PDO), si no que se ponen como parámetros y se asignan con los método `bindValue()`, por ejemplo el sql `SELECT campo FROM tabla WHERE id = :id AND password = :password` y luego `$query->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT); $query->bindValue(':pwd', $pass, PDO::PARAM_STR);`. Además de usar `filter_input()` para obtener los valores de los POST. Y para depurar te recomiendo hacer `var_dump()` para ver el estado de las variables.

Comment: Aparte de lo comentado por el compañero, la consulta SELECT también tiene un error de sintaxis,  te falta una coma después del asterisco, o mejor aún quitar el asterisco

Comment: @PhoneixS de acuerdo con lo primero, pero no con lo segundo. Con PDO el uso de `filter_input` está de más. Lo que hacen las consultas preparadas es precisamente filtar los datos de entrada. En este caso usar `filter_input`  es como lavar una ropa que ya está limpia... o hasta estropearla echándole lejía de más. PDO fue creado precisamente para desmontar ciertos mitos de que hay que filtrar por todos lados. Si aplicas bien las consultas preparadas, no hay nada más que filtrar en este caso.

Comment: @A.Cedano No está accediendo a las variables del POST solo en la consulta, también tiene longitud, latitud... Además con filter_input no solo protejes de que el valor no sea adecuado, también lo proteges de que otro código cambie el array `$_POST` y de si existe o no ese parámetro en el array. Además de que no está mal acostumbrarse a usarlo siempre ya que no influye casi nada en el rendimiento, por norma general no tienes miles de parámetros y limpiar algo ya limpio es muy rápido.

Comment: @PhoneixS los otros valores que mencionas son para insertarlos más tarde en la bd (ver sentencia `INSERT INTO` más adelante en su código). No me digas que hay que lavar una ropa ya limpia, que se le pondrá poco jabón ¡! . Igualmente gastas jabón, gastas agua y gastas tiempo... poco o mucho, gastas... y gastas la ropa. Nadie sabe si en algunos casos el mismo `filter_input` pueda alterar los datos. En todo caso, aplicar bien la consulta preparada es suficiente **en lo que atañe a la base de datos**, el uso de cualquier otro tipo de filtro es una pérdida de tiempo y de recursos.

Comment: Gracias amigos por la respuestas, pero me podrian dar una manito para solucionarlo porfavor ya llevo dias en ese error

Comment: @RafaelMeridaZambrana te he borrado tu numero de telefono porque no me parece apropiado. Toda conversacion que quieras tener puede ser aqui en los comentarios. Has de tener paciencia. Un saludo

Comment: @RafaelMeridaZambrana lo que veo a simple vista es que tienes 2 campos que parecen hacer referencia a lo mismo pero de diferente forma `u.UsuarioId` y `u.IdUsuario`, ¿por otro lado encriptas la clave de alguna forma cuándo la creas? ¿revisaste el log a ver si se esta produciondo algun errror? ¿cuál es el comportamiento actual, te hace algun tipo de redirección? ¿probaste la consulta directamente en la base de datos? ¿funciona directamente la consulta en la base de datos? En general necesitas aportar algo más de información para que podamos ayudarte. Un saludo.

Comment: @Xerif en efecto, sería un tema interesante para el chat, pero no suelo participar en chat. Comentarios borrados...